# How to show $2$ random variables are not independent.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y:=3X+1$.

How that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Clearly they are not independent since $Y$ is a function of $X$ but I don't know how to prov this formally.

My notes give two ways: show that there are two event $\{X \leq s\}, \{Y \leq t\}$ that are not independent events or to show that the joint distribution function is not the product of the individual distribution functions. I don't really understand to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are independent, then $$P(X \leq s, Y \leq t) = P(X \leq s) P(Y \leq t) \forall s,t.$$ To prove that they are not, we have to find $s,t$ such that the equality doesn't hold.

\begin{align}P(X \leq s, Y \leq t )&= P\left(X \leq s, X \leq \frac{t-1}{3}\right) \\
&=P\left(X \leq \min \left(s, \frac{t-1}{3} \right) \right)\end{align}

In particular, let's pick $s=\frac12$ and $t=2$.

$$P( X \leq s, Y \leq t)=\frac13$$

but

$$P(X \leq s) P(Y \leq t)=P(X \leq s) P \left( X \leq \frac{t-1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} \neq P(X\leq s, Y \leq t)$$

Comment: Thanks I understand now. By the way I sat reading your post trying to understand why the last line had a $Y$ where I thought it should be $X$ as soon as the penny dropped you made a typo the edit popped up. Good work!

Comment: Yup, I indeed made a typo earlier and I just caught it.

Comment: By the way is there any reason why you chose $s=1/2, t=2$ or do you just try a value that looks like it might work and hope for the best? Also can you give me a hint on how to find the density functions of $Y$?

Comment: It was actually quite arbitary for me. I know that $P(X \leq s) P(X \leq \frac{t-1}{3}) = s \left( \frac{t-1}{3}\right)$ if $0 \leq  s\leq 1$ and $0\leq \frac{t-1}{3} \leq 1$ and I just want to avoid them attaning values at the boundary like $0$ and $1$. I think you can choose any value that satisfy $0<s<1$ and $ 0 < \frac{t-1}{3} <1$ and the argument should flow through.

Comment: Any comment on the density function of $Y$?

Comment: It is an affine transformation of uniform distribution with the multiplicative part being non-zero. Hence it is uniform as well, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I suppose it would be but I still don't know how to describe the density function would it just be $3f(x)+1$ where $f(x)$ is the density of $X$ so it would be $3 \times 1+1=4$? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57145/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-ryan-s).

Answer (score 1):

Compute their covariance. Unless I'm mistaken, it's .25. If $X$ and $Y$ were independent it would be $0$.

Comment: $0$ covariance does not imply independence

Comment: Yes, but non-zero covariance does imply absence of independence!

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of $P\{X \leq \frac 12\}$? What is the value of $P\{Y \leq 2\frac 12\}$? What is the value of $P\{X\leq \frac 12,  Y \leq 2\frac 12\} = P\left(\{X\leq \frac 12\}\cap \{Y \leq 2\frac 12\}\right)$? Does it equal $P\{X \leq \frac 12\}\cdot P\{Y \leq 2\frac 12\}$? Why, or why not? Are $\{X \leq \frac 12\}$ and $\{Y \leq 2\frac 12\}$ independent events? Why or why not?  Does $F_{X,Y}\left(\frac 12, 2\frac 12\right)$ equal $F_{X}\left(\frac 12\right)F_{Y}\left(2\frac 12\right)$? Why or why not?