# Showing $X$ and $|X|$ are not independent

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ and $Y \sim a|X|+b$. Intuitively, a random variable would not be independent of a function of itself. However, I am having trouble proving this using the steps given in [an answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234610/how-to-show-2-random-variables-are-not-independent).

I got as far as
$$F_{x,y}(X < x, Y < y) = F_{x}\left(\min\left(x,\frac{y-b}{a}\right)\right)-F_{x,-x}\left(X < x, -X < \frac{y-b}{a}\right)$$

It’s the last part that is tripping me up. Any suggestions? Are there better approaches in this situation other than the approach referenced to earlier in the post? Thank you for the help ahead of time!

Comment: By far the easiest way of showing non-independence is to come up with $A$ and $B$ such that $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=0$ but $P(X\in A)\neq 0$ and $P(Y\in B)\neq 0$. Can you find two such events?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Just to take a stab at this, the probability that $X$ is negative has positive probability, while the probability that $|X|$ is negative is 0. However, the probability of $X$ and $|X|$ being negative is 0, which is the product of the probabilities, so that didn't help haha. I'll keep at it!